# Autosave ALL Excel Files Every X Minutes

Tags: vba, excel

I know there is a way to save one file every x minutes by defining it in the file's modules or Worksheets. Here is a code I found:

```
Sub SaveThis()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "SaveThis"
End Sub
```

Question: Is it possible to have this run on any active file? I was trying to use Personal Macro Workbook, but I cannot figure out how to have it automatically run on the open file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Latest patch to Office 2016 added Auto Save to Excel for stuff stored on One Drive btw.

Comment: In addition, recently they added the history and now there is a stream of BeforeSave events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the [workbooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224505(v=office.11).aspx) collection:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For w = 1 to Workbooks.Count
     Workbooks(w).Save
Next w
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```